# Ran chmod 764 /usr folder

Tags: 20.04, chmod

I ran `sudo chmod 764 /usr` and then my laptop rebooted, now I can't open Ubuntu login screen anymore. Help me please.

### Edit:

I solved it! Boot in recovering mode and then open root console. I wrote `chmod 755 /usr` and then rebooted.

Comment: Don't panic, and don't reinstall just yet; follow @jpbrain's instructions, and you should be fine. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try booting from an usb Ubuntu, mount the partition and chmod /usr to 755 for a start. Then, you will need to figure out case by case once something fails.

Good luck.

Extra info:
in an almost fresh 20.04 desktop install (on a virtual machine I have)

> find /usr | wc -l

gives about 177K files :-)

If you put in a bash shell file...

> find /usr | while read aa; do echo $aa; stat -c "%a %n" $aa; done

you will get a list of current file perms, and you could redirect that to a file as a safe measure.

regards, JP.

Comment: Yes, as long as it was only the _directory_ `/usr` and not its content as well, it should be fine to just reset the permissions for the directory. If it was really a _recursive_ chmod, it's time for reinstalling.

Comment: After mounting the partition, you will need to run `chmod 755 /mountpoint/usr`, do not run `chmod` on `/usr`

Comment: At least for the non-recursive case, it's even possible to fix from a root shell in recovery mode (provided root's login shell is in `/bin` not `/usr/bin`) - just tried it with a VM